# Four spaces not creating code block after bullet list

Tags: support

Not sure if this is the right place for the question, but in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/759435/wordpress-varnish-nginx-php5-fpm-php5-fpm-firing-every-hit/759523#759523) indenting by four spaces isn't creating a code block. It's working just fine if I ask a new question

```
like this
```

I found that adding a new line below my paragraph of text, then any text on the next line, then a blank line, then the code block made it work. I changed it to "Try this location block general pattern." Seems like a minor bug, perhaps after the bullet list is the key part.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298640/how-do-i-format-as-code-after-a-list), you have to add a comment after the list to help the markdown interpreter:

```
 - List item 
 - List item 

 <!----> 

    code
```

Will show

- List item
- List item

```
code
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. Seems like a bug being called a feature.

Comment: @Tim is there any other kind? :)

Comment: For reference: how it [should be done in CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.24/#example-222)